# Not being able to handle 401 errors

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, error-code

From my backend when I send res.status(401).send("authentication error"), and try to catch it on react front end, I am unable to check the status of the error. It always fails to pass the if statement even if the error code is 401. How do I fix this, so that when the status is 401, it goes through that if statement?

```
    onSubmit = async (e) => {
        let formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('image', this.state.file);
        try {
            const res = await axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: '/api/search',
                data: formData,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
            })
        } catch (err) {
            // authentication required 
            if (err['status'] === 401) {
                console.log('authentication problems');
                this.props.history.push('/');
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `err['status'] === 401` use `err.response.status === 401` or `err['response']['status'] === 401`

Comment: But, when i console.log(JSON.stringify(err)), I don't see any property called response. Why is that?